# Why cannot exclude 'IT_PROG' in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

The database data is in
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/aggregate-function-exercises/write-a-query-to-get-the-average-salary-for-each-job-id-excluding-programmer.php

The result:

```
sqlite> SELECT job_id, AVG(salary)
   ...> FROM employees
   ...> WHERE job_id <> 'IT_PROG'
   ...> GROUP BY job_id;
JOB_ID        AVG(salary)
------------  -----------
 AC_ACCOUNT   8300.0
 AC_MGR       12000.0
 AD_ASST      4400.0
 AD_PRES      24000.0
 AD_VP        17000.0
 FI_ACCOUNT   7920.0
 FI_MGR       12000.0
 HR_REP       6500.0
 **IT_PROG      5760.0**
 MK_MAN       13000.0
 MK_REP       6000.0
 PR_REP       10000.0
 PU_CLERK     2780.0
 PU_MAN       11000.0
 SA_MAN       12200.0
 SA_REP       8350.0
 SH_CLERK     3215.0
 ST_CLERK     2785.0
 ST_MAN       7280.0
sqlite>
```

Above result still include IT_PROG, why?

Comment: I think it works perfect.

Comment: It does seem to work based on the link you have provided. Make sure there is no whitespace in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a correct query. You should look at database settings for the "string" type.
Try also to apply trim function that removes the blank spaces:

```
SELECT job_id, AVG(salary) FROM employees WHERE TRIM(job_id) <> 'IT_PROG' GROUP BY job_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, just now I found there is indeed whitespace in it.